# list folder name and specific line on a file

Tags: linux

I have several folders:

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
...
```

In each of these folders I have a file named ds.dat. 
At line 12 of the ds.dat file I have the text I am looking for:

```
content_at_dsdat_in_folder1
content_at_dsdat_in_folder2
content_at_dsdat_in_folder3
...
```

I would like to know the linux commands to produce a text file containing both the folder name and the content on the same line:

```
folder1 content_at_dsdat_in_folder1
folder2 content_at_dsdat_in_folder2
folder3 content_at_dsdat_in_folder3
```

I have tried (retriving 12th line content):

```
ls -d */ >>test.txt; sed -sn 12p **/ds.dat >>test.txt
```

But it does:

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
content_at_dsdat_in_folder1
content_at_dsdat_in_folder2
content_at_dsdat_in_folder3
```

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I interpret your somewhat terse specs correctly and all directories do indeed have a ds.dat with 12 or more lines the following should work:

```
for i in *; do echo -n "$i "; sed -n 12p $i/ds.dat; done > test.txt
```